# Не получается создать таск

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Имею следующее:

...

```
_dbSet = context.Set<TEntity>();
```

...

```
class RepositoryForAudit<TContext, TEntity> : Repository<TContext, TEntity>
    where TContext : DbContext
    where TEntity : class
{
    public RepositoryForAudit(TContext context) : base(context)
    {
    }
    public virtual Task<TEntity> GetAll()
    {
        return Task.FromResult(_dbSet);
    }
}
```

Выдаёт ошибку. Есть только вариант _dbSet as TEntity
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Какую ошибку выдает?

Comment: `Task<Set<TEntity>>` - нэ? PS: накой здесь вообще таск?

Comment: Откровенную чушь сделать пытаетесь. Либо дайте пояснение, чего хотите добиться, либо не тратье время окружающих

Comment: Там был ещё скрин с ошибкой, но съелся. Ощибка была:
Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbSet<TEntity>>' to 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<TEntity>'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы явно напутали с типами. GetAll скорее всего должен вернуть не один объект (`TEntity`), а несколько объектов (`IEnumerable<TEntity>`).

И ваш код должен выглядеть вот так:

```
class RepositoryForAudit<TContext, TEntity> : Repository<TContext, TEntity>
    where TContext : DbContext
    where TEntity : class
{
    public RepositoryForAudit(TContext context) : base(context)
    {
    }
    public virtual Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> GetAll()
    {
        return Task.FromResult<IEnumerable<TEntity>>(_dbSet);
    }
}
```

IQueryable возвращать не стоит, чтобы вызывающий код мог одинаково вести себя как на реальной базе, так и на моке репозитория (вы ведь пишете тесты?).

Стоит учесть, что результат лучше материализовать внутри метода, чтобы не дать возможность вызывающему привести объект обратно в IQueryable:

```
class RepositoryForAudit<TContext, TEntity> : Repository<TContext, TEntity>
    where TContext : DbContext
    where TEntity : class
{
    public RepositoryForAudit(TContext context) : base(context)
    {
    }
    public virtual async Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> GetAll()
    {
        return await _dbSet.ToListAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: `IQueryable<T>` может? :)

Comment: @tym32167 нет, это ж репозиторий, он не должен давать вызывающим навесить в запрос что-то еще (иначе его нельзя будет нормально мокнуть). Вообще там должно быть `return _dbSet.ToListAsync()`, но кто его знает, подключен ли у топикастера нужный пакет

Comment: Чтобы не давать навесить еще, результат тогда надо материализовать еще внутри метода. А то получается, результат не материализовали, то есть клиент может и сам его привести к IQueryable, или может несколько раз перечислить (что обернется 2 запросами в бд)

Comment: @tym32167 да, поэтому и написал про ToListAsync. Лучше допишу в ответ.

Comment: Да думаю в этом и была проблема - перегрелся совсем(

Comment: Но ведь Task - не ковариантный тип, надо явно к интерфейсу значение как-то привести ещё.

Comment: @PavelMayorov да, сорри, писал без студии. топикастер сам докастует.

Comment: @PashaPash тогда я сам поправил

Comment: @PavelMayorov спасибо

Comment: @PavelMayorov - но ведь `async` и `await` здесь не нужны. `Task` сам по себе awaitable. PS: я использую [AsyncFixer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SemihOkur.AsyncFixer) для поиска таких ошибок.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov без них вы не сможете сделать `Task<IEnumerable<T>>` из `Task<List<T>>`