# C# асинхронная загрузка файла

Tags: c#, async-await

Целиком задача заключается в загрузке трех картинок для трех PictureBox. По условию задачи пользователь может загружать их в любой момент, поэтому я считаю, что загрузки должны выполняться асинхронно.
Сейчас я выполняю подзадачу по загрузке лишь одной картинки, и поэтому пишу следующий код:

```
async void DownloadFile(string link, string filename)
    {         
        await wc.DownloadFileTaskAsync(new Uri(link), filename);
    }

    private void PB1Download_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string filename = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\image " + downloadsCount.ToString() + ".jpg";
        string link = TB1Link.Text;
        Task.Run(() => DownloadFile(link, filename)).Wait();
        PB1.Image = new Bitmap(filename);
    }
```

Выполнение этого кода выбрасывает исключение:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Насколько я понял, это связано с тем, что загрузка Bitmap'а в PictireBox выполняется РАНЬШЕ, чем картинка скачалась, ибо задача асинхронна. Но при этом я думал, что метод Wait поможет дождаться окончания выполнения задачи и все-таки картинка будет успешно загружена в PictureBox. Что я понимаю и делаю не так?

Comment: [PictureBox.LoadAsync](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.picturebox.loadasync?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: а если я хочу скачать картинку на комп, а затем поместить ее в пикчербокс? тем самым не загружая два раза ее по ссылке

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте вот так

```
async Task DownloadFile(string link, string filename)
{         
    await wc.DownloadFileTaskAsync(new Uri(link), filename);
}

private async void PB1Download_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string filename = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), $"image{downloadsCount}.jpg");
    string link = TB1Link.Text;
    await DownloadFile(link, filename);
    PB1.Image = new Bitmap(filename);
}
```

Comment: при переписывании метода DownloadFile код не компилируется, т.к. "ожидание void невозможно"

Comment: @VanyaBelyaev вы невнимательно скопировали мой пример, попробуйте ещё раз

Comment: проблема решена, благодарю :)
а можете объяснить как это работает?

Comment: ну всё просто, у вас было `async void DownloadFile(...)` - эта функция ничего не возвращает, то есть вы её заапустить можете, но когда она закончит работу - вы не узнаете. А вот эта функция `async Task DownloadFile(...)` возвращает таск, и вы уже, зная таск, можете дождаться конца функции вот так `await DownloadFile(link, filename);`

Comment: Понял, благодарю!

Answer (score 3):

Верный ответ уже дан, но мне есть что сказать.

Самый простой способ загрузки изображения в `PictureBox` - использовате его собственные возможности. В частности, метод [PictureBox.LoadAsync](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.picturebox.loadasync?view=netframework-4.8).

Однако, вам нужно ещё и сохранить файл локально. Поэтому этот способ в данном случае не подоходит.

---

В этом методе применение async/await избыточно:

```
async Task DownloadFile(string link, string filename)
{         
    await wc.DownloadFileTaskAsync(new Uri(link), filename);
}
```

Task сам по себе является awaitable объектом, поэтому код можно переписать так:

```
Task DownloadFile(string link, string filename)
{
    return wc.DownloadFileTaskAsync(new Uri(link), filename);
}
```

Вызов метода в обоих случаях одинаков:

```
await DownloadFile("...", "...");
```

Для нахождения и устранения таких ошибок можно использовать, например, [AsyncFixer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SemihOkur.AsyncFixer).

---

Вы хотите загружать одновременно несколько картинок. Судя по названию и по сигнатуре метода, `wc` - это [WebClient](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient?view=netframework-4.8). Но этот класс не является потокобезопасным. Поэтому нужно либо для каждой загрузки создавать своей экземпляр `WebClient`, либо использовать [HttpClient](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netframework-4.8) - его экземпляр можно использовать для нескольких загрузок одновременно.

Comment: `В этом методе применение async/await избыточно:` спорное утверждение. Я тоже так думал, до момента, когда мне понадобился стек вызовов. В данном конкретном случае как написать без разницы, а в общем случае нельзя сказать, что простой возврат таска предпочтительней его асинхронного ожидания. Где то был вопрос на зту тему у нас, кстати, но не могу найти.

Comment: @tym32167 - _стек вызовов_ - ну, может быть... А так, только (ко-)(контра-)вариантность приходит в голову, зачем может понадобиться лишний await: вот [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1017540/184217) последний комментарий Павла.

Comment: благодарю за ответ! 
хотелось бы узнать, почему задача разрешилась с помощью вызова "await DownloadFile(..,..)", а именно: почему вызов этого метода через Task.Run() не сработал?

Comment: @VanyaBelyaev - tym32167 в комментарии объяснил же; на мой взгляд, вполне понятно.